# How to enable loading packages dynamicly in Palette UI

Tags: front-end, packages, palettes

Given a directory path and some `.m` files in it, I want load these packages files mannually outside notebooks, so I created Palette using code:

```
CreatePalette[
  Framed@Column[{(FileNameSetter[Dynamic[path], "Directory"]),
     Button[
      "LoadPackage", (SetOptions[Get, CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"];
                      If[ Not@DirectoryQ@ToString@path,
                          Return@$Failed
                      ];
                      Get /@ FileNames["*.m", {path}];
                     ), 
      Appearance -> "Palette"]
     }], WindowTitle -> "Test"];
```

[image]

When I want load packages, I click `[Browse]` to choose the directory firstly, then click `[LoadPackage]`, but it does not work, what's the problem?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86792/discussion-on-question-by-jerry-how-to-enable-loading-packages-dynamicly-in-pale).

Comment: Let me know if you disagree with closing. But from your answer and a conversation in chat I think that answer is what you need. It also shows why it is crucial to explain the problem and not say generic "it does not work". It can save people's time in future.

Answer (score 0):

By using the Palette `LoadPackage`, functions in package files will be loaded immediately but not listed in intellisense context at once, unless one of the functions is to be used or queried i.e. `Names["*"]`. I have tested to fix it but not succeeded.

[image]

```
SetDirectory@$TemporaryDirectory; 
CreateDirectory["files"]; 
SetDirectory@"files"; 

Export["test.m", "BeginPackage[\"MyPackage`MyPrintTool`\"] 
myPrint::usage := \"myPrint does something\" 

Begin[\"`Private`\"] (* Begin Private Context *) 

myPrint[DateString[CurrentDate[]]<>$InputFileName] 

myPrint[message_]:=Print[message] 


End[] 

EndPackage[]", "Text"]; 


CreatePalette[ 
Framed@Column[{(FileNameSetter[Dynamic[path], "Directory"]), 
Button["LoadPackage", (Get /@ FileNames["*.m", {path}];), 
Appearance -> "Palette"]}], WindowTitle -> "Test"];
```

Comment: What do you mean? Is $ContextPath not up to date?

Comment: Generally, when package files loaded, If you stike keyboards to use function, the notebook will show you a list to choose quickly(intellisense). In the upper case would not unless the new inputed funtion(s) evaluated.

Comment: Intellisense is VS related term, I for example was not aware of what are you talking about. Please target your wording at MMA users and assume nothing else or provide clarification/links etc.

Comment: I upload a picture upper, I think it's the Intellisense in MMA.

Comment: My point is that Intellisense does not mean anything in MMA. No one calls autocompletion Intellisense  here. If you google it it points at VS feature.

Comment: Ok, the original question is that, click `[LoadPackage]`, the funtions are not listed in `Autocompletion List`, i.e. `myPrint` in upper codes.